# Laravel 5.3 url with ? keyword doesn't works

Tags: php, url, redirect, laravel-5, browser

Do you guys know how to get url  with parameters and ? keyword using  laravel 5.3?
i want to get variable from URL looks like

```
http://site.dev/user/direct?TransID=42D215C2&CCDapproval=72159&PnrID=gogo&Token=42D215C&CompanyRef=gogo
```

My route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth:user'], function()
{
    Route::get('/directpay/{id}', 'DirectController@index');
}
```

ERROR

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

How to make it happen Thanks.

Comment: Your route `/directpay/{id}` does not match with the URL `user/direct` you're showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change :

```
Route::get('/directpay/{id}', 'DirectController@index');
```

to:

```
Route::get('/direct', 'DirectController@index');
```

to match this :

```
http://site.dev/user/direct?TransID=42D215C2&CCDapproval=72159&PnrID=gogo&Token=42D215C&CompanyRef=gogo
```

you can get your parameters like this :

```
$PnrID = Input::get('PnrID');
```

or like this:

```
$PnrID = request()->get('PnrID');
```

Comment: Nothing changes may you suggest any other way

Comment: @jdamour is your route under some group or is prefix with something, can you post your routes file

Comment: @jdamour ok what's the prefix of the group ? is it the word `user` ?

Comment: @ yoeunes yes it is user

Comment: ok sir, just change you route to be like this : `Route::get('/direct', 'DirectController@index');` remove that `{id}` part from there
`